# File list as optional argument for GtkApplication CLI

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, glib

I'm writing a python gtk3 app, and want to use list of files as one of optional arguments. Here is quick example how it works:

```
import gi
import sys
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib, Gio, Gtk

class Application(Gtk.Application):
    """Pure testing application without window and loop"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(application_id="org.example.myapp", flags=Gio.ApplicationFlags.HANDLES_COMMAND_LINE)
        self.add_main_option("test", ord("t"), GLib.OptionFlags.NONE, GLib.OptionArg.STRING_ARRAY, "Test file list", None)

    def do_command_line(self, command_line):
        options = command_line.get_options_dict()
        if options.contains("test"):
            print(options.lookup_value("test"))
        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.run(sys.argv)
```

if run this one with `python3 testapp.py -t file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` only first filename will be cached. It works as desired with `python3 testapp.py -t file1.txt -t file2.txt -t file3.txt`, but it's not suitable for me.

Can anyone suggest proper way for sending a file list as optional argument?

Comment: `-t "file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt"`?

Comment: The question is arguments parser, not arguments format. To be more exact launch command may be like `testapp -t ~/myfiles/*`.

At the worst I can do all as I want with python argparse module. But since GtkApplication used anyway I'm trying to master all of its aspects.